# "В цехе" или "в цеху"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно: "в цехе" или "в цеху"?

Answer (score 4):

В общем и целом правильны оба варианта: и на *-у* и на *-е*. Так же, как и мн. ч. от "цех" правильны оба варианта: *цеха* и *цехи* (согласно орфографическому словарю Ожегова и Шапиро). В современной речи конкурируют между собой две формы предложного падежа единственного числа слова цех: "в цехе" и "в цеху". Но более предпочтительным и общеупотребительным считается *в цехе*, *в цеху* устаревающий вариант.